# java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column index exception when using a simple select query in a spring boot application

Tags: oracle, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-rest

I have a spring boot application that integrates with Oracle database using spring-data-jpa.

I have an issue when I write a custom select query to fetch data from the database. The query is not at all complex. Its a simple select statement to which I am passing a bind parameter value when I invoke the spring-rest service.

This is resulting in

java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column index error

I have already tried by using the JPA repository method to check if data is being retrieved at all from the database and I have used the findOne() JPA repository method. It works absolutely fine and I am able to retrieve the data as required.

It is only when I have a method that has a custom select query in which case I encounter the issue.

CustomerController.java

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/customer")
public class CustomerController {

public static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(BugController.class);

    @Autowired
    BugService bugService;


@CrossOrigin
    @RequestMapping(value = "/open", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public Page<Bug> getOpenBugsByCustomer(@RequestBody Map<String, String> searchFilter, Pageable pageable) throws ParseException {

        logger.info("Inside getOpenBugsByCustomer() API ");

        Date reportedDateFrom = null, reportedDateBefore = null;
        Date fixedDateFrom = null, fixedDateBefore = null;
        String product = null, component = null;

        logger.info("Printing input params ::: ");

        if(searchFilter != null) {
            for(String key: searchFilter.keySet()) {
                logger.info("************************ " + key + " ::: " + searchFilter.get(key));

                if(key != null && "reportedDateFrom".equalsIgnoreCase(key)) {
                    reportedDateFrom = new SimpleDateFormat("mm/dd/yyyy").parse(searchFilter.get(key));
                }

                if(key != null && "reportedDateBefore".equalsIgnoreCase(key)) {
                    reportedDateBefore = new SimpleDateFormat("mm/dd/yyyy").parse(searchFilter.get(key));
                }

                if(key != null && "fixedDateFrom".equalsIgnoreCase(key)) {
                    fixedDateFrom = new SimpleDateFormat("mm/dd/yyyy").parse(searchFilter.get(key));
                }

                if(key != null && "fixedDateFrom".equalsIgnoreCase(key)) {
                    fixedDateBefore = new SimpleDateFormat("mm/dd/yyyy").parse(searchFilter.get(key));
                }

                if(key != null && "product".equalsIgnoreCase(key)) {
                    product = searchFilter.get(key);
                }

                if(key != null && "component".equalsIgnoreCase(key)) {
                    component = searchFilter.get(key);
                }
            }
        }

        Page<Bug> openCustomerBugs = bugService.findOpenBugsByCustomer(reportedDateFrom, reportedDateBefore, fixedDateFrom, fixedDateBefore, product, component, pageable);


        logger.info("**************************** Printing Bug information ****************************");

        return openCustomerBugs;
    }

}
```

BugService.java (Interface)

```
import java.util.Date;

import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable;

import com.app.oracle.OMBugDBAnalyzer.entity.Bug;

public interface BugService {

    Page<Bug> findOpenBugsByCustomer(Date reportedDateFrom, Date reportedDateBefore, Date fixedDateFrom, Date fixedDateBefore, String product, String component, Pageable pageable);

}
```

BugServiceImpl.java

```
import java.util.Date;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.app.oracle.OMBugDBAnalyzer.entity.Bug;
import com.app.oracle.OMBugDBAnalyzer.repository.BugRepository;

@Service
public class BugServiceImpl implements BugService {

    @Autowired
    BugRepository bugRepository;

    public static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(BugServiceImpl.class);

    @Override
    public Page<Bug> findOpenBugsByCustomer(Date reportedDateFrom, Date reportedDateBefore, Date fixedDateFrom,
            Date fixedDateBefore, String product, String component, Pageable pageable) {

        logger.info("Inside findOpenBugsByCustomer() API ");

        logger.info("Printing input params ");
        logger.info("*******************************************************");
        logger.info("reportedDateFrom :::::::::::: " + reportedDateFrom);
        logger.info("reportedDateBefore :::::::::::: " + reportedDateBefore);
        logger.info("fixedDateFrom :::::::::::: " + fixedDateFrom);
        logger.info("fixedDateBefore :::::::::::: " + fixedDateBefore);
        logger.info("product :::::::::::: " + product);
        logger.info("component :::::::::::: " + component);

        logger.info("Printing page params ");
        logger.info("Page Size ::::::::: "  + pageable.getPageSize());
        logger.info("Page Number ::::::::: "  + pageable.getPageNumber());

        return bugRepository.findOpenBugsByCustomer(product, pageable);
    }

}
```

BugRepository.java (Interface that extends the JPA Repository)

```
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;

import com.app.oracle.OMBugDBAnalyzer.entity.Bug;

public interface BugRepository extends JpaRepository <Bug, Long>{

    @Query(value = 
            "select * from rpthead r where r.product_id = ?1"
            + " \n-- #pageable\n",
           countQuery = 
            "select count(*) from product r where r.product_id = ?1", nativeQuery = true)
    Page<Bug> findOpenBugsByCustomer(String product, Pageable pageable);

}
```

Exception stack trace

```
java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column index
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.setIntInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:5223) ~[ojdbc7-12.1.0.1.jar:12.1.0.1.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.setInt(OraclePreparedStatement.java:5210) ~[ojdbc7-12.1.0.1.jar:12.1.0.1.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.setInt(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:209) ~[ojdbc7-12.1.0.1.jar:12.1.0.1.0]
    at org.hibernate.dialect.pagination.AbstractLimitHandler.bindLimitParameters(AbstractLimitHandler.java:156) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.dialect.pagination.AbstractLimitHandler.bindLimitParametersAtEndOfQuery(AbstractLimitHandler.java:128) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:1947) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1898) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1876) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:919) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:336) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2617) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2600) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2429) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2424) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader.list(CustomLoader.java:336) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.listCustomQuery(SessionImpl.java:1967) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.list(AbstractSessionImpl.java:322) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SQLQueryImpl.list(SQLQueryImpl.java:125) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:606) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:483) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$PagedExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:190) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.22.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:89) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.22.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:128) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.22.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:118) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.22.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:494) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.22.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:477) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.22.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.24.RELEASE.jar:4.3.24.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:56) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.22.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.24.RELEASE.jar:4.3.24.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99) ~[spring-tx-4.3.24.RELEASE.jar:4.3.24.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:283) ~[spring-tx-4.3.24.RELEASE.jar:4.3.24.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96) ~[spring-tx-4.3.24.RELEASE.jar:4.3.24.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.24.RELEASE.jar:4.3.24.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136) ~[spring-tx-4.3.24.RELEASE.jar:4.3.24.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.24.RELEASE.jar:4.3.24.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:133) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.22.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.24.RELEASE.jar:4.3.24.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92) ~[spring-aop-4.3.24.RELEASE.jar:4.3.24.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.24.RELEASE.jar:4.3.24.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:57) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.22.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.24.RELEASE.jar:4.3.24.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213) ~[spring-aop-4.3.24.RELEASE.jar:4.3.24.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy77.findOpenBugsByCustomer(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.app.oracle.OMBugDBAnalyzer.service.BugServiceImpl.findOpenBugsByCustomer(BugServiceImpl.java:42) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.app.oracle.OMBugDBAnalyzer.controller.CustomerController.getOpenBugsByCustomer(CustomerController.java:75) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205) ~[spring-web-4.3.24.RELEASE.jar:4.3.24.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133) ~[spring-web-4.3.24.RELEASE.jar:4.3.24.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.24.RELEASE.jar:4.3.24.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:854) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.24.RELEASE.jar:4.3.24.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:765) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.24.RELEASE.jar:4.3.24.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.24.RELEASE.jar:4.3.24.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.24.RELEASE.jar:4.3.24.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.24.RELEASE.jar:4.3.24.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.24.RELEASE.jar:4.3.24.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.24.RELEASE.jar:4.3.24.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.40.jar:8.5.40]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.24.RELEASE.jar:4.3.24.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.40.jar:8.5.40]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.40.jar:8.5.40]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.40.jar:8.5.40]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.40.jar:8.5.40]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.40.jar:8.5.40]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.40.jar:8.5.40]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-4.3.24.RELEASE.jar:4.3.24.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.24.RELEASE.jar:4.3.24.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.40.jar:8.5.40]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.40.jar:8.5.40]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:109) ~[spring-web-4.3.24.RELEASE.jar:4.3.24.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.24.RELEASE.jar:4.3.24.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.40.jar:8.5.40]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.40.jar:8.5.40]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-4.3.24.RELEASE.jar:4.3.24.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.24.RELEASE.jar:4.3.24.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.40.jar:8.5.40]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.40.jar:8.5.40]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) ~[spring-web-4.3.24.RELEASE.jar:4.3.24.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.24.RELEASE.jar:4.3.24.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.40.jar:8.5.40]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.40.jar:8.5.40]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.40.jar:8.5.40]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.40.jar:8.5.40]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:493) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.40.jar:8.5.40]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:137) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.40.jar:8.5.40]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.40.jar:8.5.40]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.40.jar:8.5.40]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.40.jar:8.5.40]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:798) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.40.jar:8.5.40]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.40.jar:8.5.40]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:808) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.40.jar:8.5.40]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1498) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.40.jar:8.5.40]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.40.jar:8.5.40]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_211]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_211]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.40.jar:8.5.40]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_211]
```

I tried to print the query by enabling the following two properties.

```
spring.jpa.show-sql = true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
```

I see the following query printed in the console

```
Hibernate: 
    select
        * 
    from
        ( select
            r.rptno,
            r.customer,
            r.status,
            r.subject 
        from
            rpthead r 
        where
            r.product_id = ?   -- #pageable ) 
    where
        rownum <= ?
2019-05-25 23:11:10.294  WARN 9207 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 17003, SQLState: 99999
2019-05-25 23:11:10.294 ERROR 9207 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Invalid column index
Error encountered ::: 
org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: could not execute query; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute query
```

I thought that that was the standard way to return queries with pagination.
I definitely saw that working in mysql. Is it going to be different if its Oracle database?

Or is it that I am not looking at it from a right direction?

If anyone has any clue about this issue, i would really appreciate that as I am stuck and not able to make any progress.

Hi Bob, Sorry for bothering you. Your suggestion did work. However, If I add another query condition to the above SQL query (which of course is a valid one - tested via SQL developer), leads to the following exception.

Not sure whats going wrong here.

I thought i have really checked everything out here.

```
Hibernate: 
    select
        * 
    from
        ( select
            * 
        from
            rpthead r 
        where
            r.status NOT IN (
                11,30,40
            )  
            and r.product_id = ?  /* #pageable */ ) 
    where
        rownum <= ?
Hibernate: 
    select
        count(*) 
    from
        product r 
    where
        r.status NOT IN (
            11,30,40
        )  
        and r.product_id = ?
```

Exception stacktrace

```
2019-05-26 00:13:35.096  WARN 11106 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 904, SQLState: 42000
2019-05-26 00:13:35.096 ERROR 11106 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : ORA-00904: "R"."STATUS": invalid identifier

Error encountered ::: 
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:261)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:244)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:525)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:59)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:209)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:147)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:133)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:57)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy99.findOpenBugsByCustomer(Unknown Source)
    at com.app.oracle.OMBugDBAnalyzer.service.BugServiceImpl.findOpenBugsByCustomer(BugServiceImpl.java:47)
    at com.app.oracle.OMBugDBAnalyzer.controller.CustomerController.getOpenBugsByCustomer(CustomerController.java:76)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:854)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:765)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:109)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:493)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:137)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:798)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:808)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1498)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
```

It is reporting r.status is an invalid identifier. However, that's incorrect. I do have the following SQL query setup in my SQL Developer and that works absolutely fine.

SELECT
    *
FROM
    rpthead r
WHERE
    r.product_id = 10904
    AND r.status NOT IN (
        11,
        30,
        40
    )
    AND upper(r.category) != upper('INT');

Comment: no need to use " \n-- #pageable\n", leave it out

Comment: Hi Dirk. Thank you for your help. Should i retain everything else of how the method has been declared in the repository method with the native SQL query leaving only the part that you have mentioned (or) should I be removing the countQuery also? If its not asking much, can you show me from the BugRepository interface code above, what should be changed?

Comment: think you're ok with ```@Query(value = "select r from rpthead r where r.product_id = ?1"```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the final version of the query one of the parentheses is commented out:

```
select
    * 
from
    ( select
        r.rptno,
        r.customer,
        r.status,
        r.subject 
    from
        rpthead r 
    where
        r.product_id = ?   -- #pageable )  <<== this parentheses is commented out
where
    rownum <= ?
```

I suggest that you use `/*...*/` comments around #pageable:

```
@Query(value = 
        "select * from rpthead r where r.product_id = ?1"
        + " \n/* #pageable */ \n",
       countQuery = 
        "select count(*) from product r where r.product_id = ?1", nativeQuery = true)
Page<Bug> findOpenBugsByCustomer(String product, Pageable pageable);
```

Comment: Thanks Bob. Your suggestion worked. :) I was totally clueless on how to proceed. Thanks a ton.

Comment: Hi Bob, I am facing further issues. Your suggestion worked, but when I modified the query to include one more where clause condition, it is reporting errors and the where clause added is more a static clause and with no bind parameters. I have updated the thread to indicate the SQL query change and the error reported. Would really appreciate if you can help with some pointers here.

Comment: You should really ask another question, but OK - you have two queries in your question, one against `RPTHEAD` and one against `PRODUCT`. I don't know which is being executed when you get the error message `"R"."STATUS": invalid identifier` which indicates that either the `RPTHEAD` table or the `PRODUCT` table does not have a field named `STATUS`. You'll need to narrow it down from there. Best of luck.